# How to write a regex for web scraping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have this text on a website I want to scrape:

```
event: new SEvent({"event_id":"Id","date":"Sat 27 Aug 2016"})
```

I want to pass this from my controller to my JavaScript file, which is already set up.

I'm having issues parsing the information so that only this is returned:

```
SEvent({"event_id":"Id","date":"Sat 27 Aug 2016"})
```

Here's what I tried to no avail:

```
info = text.to_s.scan(/\"(event)/).uniq
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with following regex:

```
/event: new (\w+\([^)]+\))/
```

Comment: The above you stated works a dream except when im sending the thing to postman and it looks like this in postman: `SEEvent({\"event_id\":\"Id\",\"date\":\"Sat  5 Nov 2016, 19:30\`

Comment: any ideas how to make it more json friendly?

Comment: "any ideas how to make it more json friendly?" should be a separate question. Jumping from one problem to another in comments results in confusing questions and answers, and dilutes the power of Stack Overflow, which is to have a separate page for individual programming problems.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you basically want to remove the "event: new " part of the input string? Maybe I misread your question - if not, this is what you could do:

```
input = 'event: new SEvent({"event_id":"Id","date":"Sat 27 Aug 2016"})'

input.gsub('event: new ', '')
=> 'SEvent({"event_id":"Id","date":"Sat 27 Aug 2016"})'
```

or a safer option

```
input.gsub('event: new SEvent', 'SEvent')`
=> 'SEvent({"event_id":"Id","date":"Sat 27 Aug 2016"})'
```

Comment: Don't use `gsub`, unless you're trying to remove multiple occurrences at one time. `sub` would be faster and the preferred choice usually.

Comment: You don't know if he actually wants to remove multiple occurrences. "Faster" is usually not an argument, I doubt that there will be any noticable performance difference for most cases.

Comment: There can be big differences, it depends on the case. In this case, it'll be small for each string unless there are a massive number of occurrences being processed; the OP's use of `uniq` hints that there are multiple occurrences being processed. (But the code and question also hint at confusion of how to write a solution.) It's always better to first use the methods that are faster unless the criteria/conditions demand otherwise. That's just lessons learned.

Answer (score 0):

`info` will be an array containing only the matches.

Currently you're matching only the string `"event`, but to match the entire string you want, you can use something like:

```
scan(/SEvent\(\{\"event[^\)]*\)/)
```

That will match the opening identifier string `SEvent({"event` then everything up to the next closing parentesis. which should capture your entire desired string

```
SEvent({"event_id":"Id","date":"Sat 27 Aug 2016"})
```

Also, I wanted to mention the square brackets with the carat `[^\)]*` means match 0 or more characters EXCEPT closing parenthesis.